# Chome is blocking the iframe of my next js app. How can i fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, content-security-policy

I am trying to render i frame in my nextjs app.

The iframe is working in `Firefox` but is being blocked in the chrome.

Rendering the iframe is quite simple. here is the complete code

```
<iframe
      sandbox="allow-scripts"
      className={styles.iframe}
      src='https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf'
      title="dummy report"
 ></iframe>
```

When I tried to google about this issue. I saw that i need to change in the `next.config.js`

So i tried my best to change the header but its not working

Here is my `next.config.js`

```
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
  default-src 'self' *;
  script-src 'self' *;
  child-src example.com *;
  style-src 'self' example.com *;
  font-src 'self' *;  
  frame-src 'self' *;
  object-src 'self' blob *;
`

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Content-Security-Policy",
            value: ContentSecurityPolicy.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " ").trim(),
          },
          {
            key: 'X-Frame-Options',
            value: ''
          },

        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Here is the link to [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/security-headers) document

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using  HTML tag for external resources in NextJs

```
<div>
     <object data="https://www.whatever.com/" width="100%" height="725" type="text/html">
     </object>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work for me